# Is it possible for computers to tell how many people are speaking in a audio recording

Tags: tensorflow, audio-recognition, machine-translation, question-answering

Suppose I had a audio recording of 15 students saying "Here" all at the same. Can I tell how many students were speaking and who they were using machine learning?

I want to create a school attendance application that the students can all scream "Here" when the teacher asks them and it would mark everyone in class absent or present based of what the model pridicted from hearing the students scream "Here".

Comment: ML can give you an answer, but this might not be the correct one ;)  I think this is unlikely to work well enough.

Comment: @Erwan .So you're saying I can divide an audio recording of ten individuals yelling "Here" into ten different recordings of each individual? Please let me know if you have any tools for this type of activity. I know that if I break the audio recording into ten different audio recordings, I'll be able to tell which voice is whose. Is this correct? Because I have used TensorFlow so little, I am stating this.

Comment: No, I'm saying that you could try but it's unlikely to work. I'm no expert though.

Comment: Doing it automatically in, when it is one person at a time (where order is unknown), would already be quite challenging in practice. Even challenge-response (system controls when each student should respond) might not work well in a classroom setting.